# Merge [presentation] with [presentation-design]

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the tag [presentation-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentation-design), which has 48 questions and a tag description, as well as the [presentation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentation) tag, with only 17 questions and no tag description. To me there doesn't seem to be a difference between the two. Can we get these tags merged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference.

One is about designing presentations; the other about presenting designs... There is certainly overlap but it is an important distinction. It is, e.g., the difference between creating a PowerPoint presentation template for a client and presenting your logo concepts to another.

To illustrate my point, compare a few questions from each...

A few [presentation-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentation-design) questions about designing presentations:

- [Professional Powerpoint design from Indesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65421/52050)
- [PowerPoint: Proceed to next slide on click, regardless of the ongoing animations in the current slide](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/96567/52050)
- [What are the Google Slide background dimensions?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/70585/52050)

Likewise, a few [presentation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentation) questions about presenting designs:

- [In what cases should I pay attention to my design's colour scheme when presenting it? When I do, what is a good way to do so?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/50728/52050)
- [Best practices for client presentation when not face to face](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/53277/52050)
- [How to present a print project to a client?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/46649/52050)

The tag wikis should be updated to reflect this.